# Where is the subscribe function coming from in the SolidJS docs?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, solid-js

I have checked thoroughly and found that SolidJS does not have an observable where one can subscribe to store reactive primitives, only signals as far as I know. What is the observable used here if that is the case?

```js
const unsubscribe = store.subscribe(({ todos }) => {
  setState('todos', reconcile(todos))
});

onCleanup(() => unsubscribe());
```

If subscribing to such values is not possible, how do I track the changes inside my store and execute some statements accordingly with the store just as a tracking dependency?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: You can use the "Code Sample" feature to make the code more readable in your posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solid has a `subscribe` function exported from the core library so that you can listen to external observables, like the ones created by RxJS, by creating a signal.

An RxJS observable pushes changes to its listeners via an event. The signal you get from the subscribe method will allow you to track the changes.

So subscribe is a method to interface with other reactive libraries.

Now about the subscribe function on the snippet you share, it seems the store value is an external observable that emits `todos`. The callback receives this todos values and updates a solid store by setting new todos. The snippet demonstrates how to use the reconcile function.